# How to have a repeater split the entire width available between its children in WinUI?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefintion Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefintion Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefintion Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <control Grid.Column="0" />
    <control Grid.Column="1" />
    <control Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

But for an arbitrary collection of items as provided by the view model. The closest I've gotten was this:

```
        <ItemsRepeater Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SmtState.LoadTypes}">
            <ItemsRepeater.Layout>
                <UniformGridLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemsStretch="Fill" MaximumRowsOrColumns="{x:Bind ViewModel.SmtState.LoadTypes.Count}" />
            </ItemsRepeater.Layout>

            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- template here -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsRepeater>
```

Which, provided there's enough space, will do what I want it to do. However when I make the window smaller it will start behaving like a wrap panel, moving the extra items on the next "line", instead of squishing its children:

[image]

I also hate that I have to specify the maximum number of items, but I can live with that. `StackLayout` and `WrapLayout` predictably also didn't help, since they don't use the entire space.

So, is there a layout of some kind that can simply divide its entire space in one direction (horizontal in my case) to its children, and not allow them to use more than available? Or any suggestions of how I could write one?

Comment: As an additional problem with the existing solution, making the width of the data grid's columns `*` (to use all available space equally) will make each data grid use the entire page width, forcing all 3 components to stack vertically (again, like it's some kind of a `WrapPanel` from WPF. Note that without it, there's some empty space at the end of the datagrids' columns that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying with `Layout`, you can create a custom `Grid` and use it in `ItemTemplate`.

For example:

**HorizontalUniformGrid.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ItemsRepeaterTest;

public class HorizontalUniformGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemsSource),
            typeof(IEnumerable<object>),
            typeof(HorizontalUniformGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, (d, e) => (d as HorizontalUniformGrid)?.RefreshGrid()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemTemplate),
            typeof(DataTemplate),
            typeof(HorizontalUniformGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    private void RefreshGrid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
        Children.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < ItemsSource.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (ItemTemplate.LoadContent() is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
            {
                ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
                frameworkElement.DataContext = ItemsSource.ElementAt(i);
                SetColumn(frameworkElement, i);
                Children.Add(frameworkElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <local:HorizontalUniformGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubItems, Mode=OneWay}">
                <local:HorizontalUniformGrid.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:HorizontalUniformGrid.ItemTemplate>
            </local:HorizontalUniformGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsRepeater>
```

Comment: Hm, so turn the grid itself into a repeater. Interesting, this could work. It's just *so ugly* and *so wrong*, the grid is supposed to be the repeater's layouting mechanism, not the other way around.

Comment: Not turning a `Grid` into an `ItemsRepeater`. Just a custom `Grid` for sub items layout on each row.